# how can I smooth pixels on a DP monitor?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dvi, displayport, font-smoothing

I've got 2 monitors, same model ([LP2361](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824221022)). But they connect via different cables because of what ports I have on my video card. The monitor that connects via display port has very chunky text. I took a cellphone shot of it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91aou.jpg. If you look at the paragraph text on the left side (DVI port) and right side (DP) the right side text is really blocky and harder to read. I've gone through all the settings on the monitor and don't see anything that helps.

Updated video driver. No change.

How can I fix pixelated/chunky text on a monitor using DP connection? I'm using Win7 and an Ubuntu 12 VM. The issue is more pronounced in Ubuntu but also present in Windows.